# How to create a union of a list of types from a mapped type?

Tags: typescript

I have a notification system in my app, which I want to make type safe. So I defined a type holding the possible notification IDs:

```
export interface IRequisitionCallBackMethods {
    "open": (requestId: string, values: { type: string; name: string }) => Promise<void>;
    "close": (requestId: string, values: { name: string }) => Promise<void>;
    "delete": (requestId: string, values: { id: number }) => Promise<void>;
}
```

In my class I can now use a type mapping to define a registration function for callbacks, triggered when one of the events are sent:

```
export class RequisitionHub {

    public register = <K extends keyof IRequisitionCallBackMethods>(event: K,
        callback: IRequisitionCallBackMethods[K]): void => {
        // todo
    };
}
```

That works so far, but only for a single event + callback combination. In my old implementation I can register the same callback for many events. That's why I need a way to build a type union out of the possible callback types. Is that possible and how?

I tried:

```
export class RequisitionHub {
    public register2 = <K extends (keyof IRequisitionCallBackMethods | Array<keyof IRequisitionCallBackMethods>)>
    (event: K,
        callback: <union of IRequisitionCallBackMethods valid for K>): void => {
        // todo
    };
}
```

but didn't find anything that would work for the callback union type.

For comparison, that's what I currently use:

```
export type RequisitionCallback = (requestId: string, args?: unknown[]) => Promise<void>;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the whole point here. In the old (current) implementation I use an `unknown` type instead (actually an array of `unknown`). So I could cast that to the expected types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here. If we start with your `IRequisitionCallBackMethods` type, we can get the types of the individual functions and — more usefully — their `values` types:

```typescript
export interface IRequisitionCallBackMethods {
    "open": (requestId: string, values: { type: string; name: string }) => Promise<void>;
    "close": (requestId: string, values: { name: string }) => Promise<void>;
    "delete": (requestId: string, values: { id: number }) => Promise<void>;
}

export type IRequisitionOpenCallback = IRequisitionCallBackMethods["open"];
export type IRequisitionOpenValues = Parameters<IRequisitionOpenCallback>[1];

export type IRequisitionCloseCallback = IRequisitionCallBackMethods["close"];
export type IRequisitionCloseValues = Parameters<IRequisitionCloseCallback>[1];

export type IRequisitionDeleteCallback = IRequisitionCallBackMethods["delete"];
export type IRequisitionDeleteValues = Parameters<IRequisitionDeleteCallback>[1];
```

Or alternatively, you could start with those and then define `IRequisitionCallBackMethods` using those types.

```typescript
export type IRequisitionOpenValues = { type: string; name: string };
export type IRequisitionOpenCallback = (requestId: string, values: IRequisitionOpenValues) => Promise<void>;

export type IRequisitionCloseValues = { name: string };
export type IRequisitionCloseCallback = (requestId: string, values: IRequisitionCloseValues) => Promise<void>;

export type IRequisitionDeleteValues = { id: number };
export type IRequisitionDeleteCallback = (requestId: string, values: IRequisitionDeleteValues) => Promise<void>;

export interface IRequisitionCallBackMethods {
    "open": IRequisitionOpenCallback;
    "close": IRequisitionCloseCallback;
    "delete": IRequisitionDeleteCallback;
}
```

Either way, you now have types you can readily use to declare a handler for multiple events:

```typescript
const handler = async (requestId: string, values: IRequisitionOpenValues | IRequisitionCloseValues) => {
    console.log(requestId);
    if ("type" in values) {
        console.log(values.type, values.name);
    } else {
        console.log(values.name);
    }
};

const r = new RequisitionHub();
r.register("open", handler);
r.register("close", handler);
```

[Playground for first approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQCVgBHAVwQGcEYEIkBhTAG2YCEcBrAWWBgAsIAE0pwA3gCg40uACIIYYElkAuOAAoopMsEox8QtXqjIA5gBo4ANxY7KasXBgBPRUZgmkpgNxwkmAFtgd09TOABfAEo4AF4APjgABSgIAKpgAB4rCAQhOO8pGVlsZghKYFUNLXJdfUM4YzNLG2Y7Bz9A4IaPMwjo+KSUtPKsnLyCmTkhYGY+CrVNbVqDEKbrW1123LUkMgCAIzQ+2ITk1PTR3PyJcIlQSFgnVzwibSoaOiQAeUVGFmZ9lxYgRiOR3rR6ExWBxsDw+IIRABteS-WQAXQK92g8BcihBb2oEO+vwAahtRDEkpgoJ1UFBKBlXmDCZ8fkooQCuHFEQBGDESO7gbFPPFMigsyGlcocwGw4Fi8GfDkwuECYSUZElMoVflYx64l6g8UfSXasmtXTAxLU2loBkKiWMKXAGVc3n8wUPHHPfHMk1IAAiMzmrrllId-uVXF4aqRsmms1Q6MxQv1PojRKDieA5rsVptQTp9qNivoWZD-1lnG5fIKnuFJUwlFEJcdAAkyPtxIVpGBO8wENg4FpTFQ6cCMgBpOCgVBIERwTjAZwQdC+41EqOwmMIyhxdTAKxKGBqSfmHuTODYStcNQZpX-FU79WIydoyJqbK5E7dy8yAD0-5OMIEAXuEBS3BI2D0HocD8Jg86zFAwJNs4SBDosNR6Cs3ShM05J3q2-pskguaWgAPuupZOma5L9AkkiTNBSCUBAswAHSlKYmF2HUkQTDICBruosgGrIiBIOsFqUNEjF-leMFscAnEQNxLR2OxBr4dJ7H+EE-FgTOzDlL+8nMaxHFceo6m6LpnQGZMtzgQK5nwMhlJIMAADucBEUSHb7OoBlQOxI5jmgIkKEosiWPBiFoMFoXAKOegRcUzoxXBCFCEh-FAA)

[Playground for second approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-CSVGTDsOPeZElcegAfKufhcdLXCuCrGke5CEBAAIAHRtOID5Ej4KQOkq+CVq4KofCqcBiGEIJpGBa5wBBUGwfBrgHF4MEfG+1H9MAKF7mo+aMB0q7EaR0HAHBEAIVRrAwQxTHGv6GgcqR8BXjIwAAO5wOGVLRjYrhMVAMHppmcKYeqiQqiEZ4XnCakacAGbCNpKqmvM+mnuePiXkxQA)

Or if you prefer, type the function rather than the `values`, either works:

```typescript
const handler: IRequisitionOpenCallback & IRequisitionCloseCallback = async (requestId, values) => {
    console.log(requestId);
    if ("type" in values) {
        console.log(values.type, values.name);
    } else {
        console.log(values.name);
    }
};
```

Comment: That's a usable solution (though the playground doesn't work out of the box, because of the `export`s - just a minor problem). The only thing that bothers me is that I have to manually specify the value types in each handler, instead of TS figuring this out for me. Also, you didn't handle a list of request types in the register call, but that's not a big deal.

Comment: @MikeLischke - In my experience, *most* playgrounds don't run (though they have that feature now), they just show the type side of things and that was what was relevant here, so I didn't bother to comment out `export`. I didn't think the question was about the `register` call, but rather about the type of the handler. Re `values`, you can type the function itself instead, matter of preference. I've added an example at the end.